# Anyone familiar with Muller's Algorithm?? Having trouble with coding.

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble getting this code for Muller's algorithm to work properly for a class that only involves basic python programming. My program does not yet include anything for imaginary numbers like the output does, and my stopping criteria also is not working properly, but right now I am mostly concerned about getting the numbers in the output below to print correctly. I posted the output as code because I am new to this site and it kept giving me an error saying that my "code was not formatted correctly"

Any help is VERY MUCH appreciated!

```
When f=(x-5)*(x-4)*(x+7)
and initial guesses are 1,3,and -10 
and tolerance = 0.000001

The output of this code should look like this:
The initial estimates to the root are:
f( 1 )= 96
f( 3 )= 20
f( -10 )= -630
0 : estimate to the root is f( 1 )= 96

1 : estimate to the root is f( (-4.102012878968893+0j) )= (213.71097514696675+0j)  

2 : estimate to the root is f( (3.463202253458595+0j) )= (8.63161417086553+0j)

3 : estimate to the root is f( (3.6797449479714586+0j) )= (4.515592141362759+0j) 

4 : estimate to the root is f( (3.9234514667540585+0j) )= (0.9001820953746444+0j)

5 : estimate to the root is f( (3.9988300605239253+0j) )= (0.012883020219233893+0j)

6 : estimate to the root is f( (3.9999973985379675+0j) )= (2.861615003307639e-05+0j)

The approximation to the root is f( (3.999999999978821+0j) ) = (2.329696435810382e-
10+0j)
```

Here is my actual code:

```
import string
from math import *
from cmath import *

def evalFunction(f,x):
    x=eval(f)
    return x

def main():
    f= input("Input the function: ")
    p0=eval(input("Input the first estimate to the root of the function: "))
    p1=eval(input("Input the second estimate to the root of the function: "))
    p2=eval(input("Input the third estimate to the root of the function: "))
    t=eval(input("Enter the tolerance "))

    fp0=evalFunction(f,p0)
    fp1=evalFunction(f,p1)
    fp2=evalFunction(f,p2)

    print("The initial estimates to the root are:")
    print("f(",p0,")=",fp0)
    print("f(",p1,")=",fp1)
    print("f(",p2,")=",fp2)
    count=0
    print(count,": estimate to the root is f(",p0,")=",fp0)
    fp3=1

    while count<30:
        while (abs(fp3))>=t:
            fp0=evalFunction(f,p0)
            fp1=evalFunction(f,p1)
            fp2=evalFunction(f,p2)


            #Computes a,b,c 
            o=fp1-fp2
            n=fp0-fp2
            s=p1-p2
            r=p0-p2
            denom=r*s*(p0-p1)
            a=(s*n-r*o)/denom
            b=((r**2)*o-(s**2)*n)/denom
            c=fp2
            print()

            count=count+1

            #Computes the roots
            x1= (-2*c)/(b+(b**2-4*a*c)**.5)
            x2=(-2*c)/(b-(b**2-4*a*c)**.5)

            if b>0:
                p3= p2+x1
                fp3=evalFunction(f,p3)
                print(count,": estimate to the root is f(",p3,")=",fp3)
                print()

            else:
                p3= p2+x2
                fp3=evalFunction(f,p3)
                print(count,": estimate to the root is f(",p3,")=",fp3)
                print()

            p2=p3        

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't perfectly clear what aspect of the program isn't working for you, except possibly for the code hanging up once the tolerance is met, because `count` is incremented inside the inner loop, which no longer executes after tolerance is met, causing the outer loop, `while count<30:`, to run forever.

Anyhow, changing the sequence `while count<30:` and `while (abs(fp3))>=t:` to `while count<30 and (abs(fp3))>=t:` fixes that problem.  See note at end of answer re problem with `p0` and `p1` not updating inside the loop, a problem that I imagine wrecks the convergence rate.

Regarding the output formatting, see use of the `format` function in the code below.  Note, in this code I added spaces around most of the equal signs, for better readability, and added input of parameters via command line.   Parameters not entered on the command line are still prompted for.  I don't know if command line parameters are picked up in the same manner on MS-Windows machines.

Note, you can print real and complex parts of numbers with different or the same numbers of decimal places; for example, `c=3-5j; d=4.4+5.5j; print ('d: {.real:7.2f} {.imag:+.3f}j  c: {:9.4f}'.format(d,d, c))` produces `d:    4.40 +5.500j  c: 3.0000-5.0000j`.  For more information about formatting, see [Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) docs.

With the program as revised below, running it on my Linux system  via `./mullermethod.py '(x-5)*(x-4)*(x+7)' 1 3 -10 0.000001` (the same parameters you entered at prompts) prints

```
The initial estimates to a root are:
f( 1.0 ) =  96.0
f( 3.0 ) =  20.0
f( -10.0 ) =  -630.0
 0: estimate to a root is f(  1.00000000000000) =  96.00000000000000
 1: estimate to a root is f( -4.10201287896889) = 213.71097514696675
 2: estimate to a root is f(  3.46320225345860) =   8.63161417086548
 3: estimate to a root is f(  3.90342357843416) =   1.15470992046251
 4: estimate to a root is f(  3.98002449809592) =   0.22371275706982
 5: estimate to a root is f(  3.99575149263503) =   0.04691400247817
 6: estimate to a root is f(  3.99909106270745) =   0.01000657113716
 7: estimate to a root is f(  3.99980529453210) =   0.00214213924168
 8: estimate to a root is f(  3.99995828046651) =   0.00045893227349
 9: estimate to a root is f(  3.99999106024078) =   0.00009833815063
10: estimate to a root is f(  3.99999808434378) =   0.00002107225517
11: estimate to a root is f(  3.99999958950253) =   0.00000451547380
12: estimate to a root is f(  3.99999991203627) =   0.00000096760109
```

and then the program exits.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.2
from math import *
from cmath import *

def evalFunction(f,x):
    return eval(f)

def main():
    from sys import argv
    f  = argv[1]           if len(argv)>1 else input("Input the function: ")
    p0 = float(argv[2])    if len(argv)>2 else eval(input("Input the first estimate to a root of the function: "))
    p1 = float(argv[3])    if len(argv)>3 else eval(input("Input the next  estimate to a root of the function: "))
    p2 = float(argv[4])    if len(argv)>4 else eval(input("Input the third estimate to a root of the function: "))
    toler = float(argv[5]) if len(argv)>5 else eval(input("Enter the tolerance: "))

    fp0 = evalFunction(f,p0)
    fp1 = evalFunction(f,p1)
    fp2 = evalFunction(f,p2)

    print("The initial estimates to a root are:")
    print("f(",p0,") = ",fp0)
    print("f(",p1,") = ",fp1)
    print("f(",p2,") = ",fp2)
    count = 0
    print ('{:2}: estimate to a root is f({:18.14f}) = {:18.14f}'.format(count,p0,fp0))
    fp3 = 1e9

    while count<30 and abs(fp3) >= toler:
        fp0 = evalFunction(f,p0)
        fp1 = evalFunction(f,p1)
        fp2 = evalFunction(f,p2)

        #Computes a,b,c 
        o = fp1-fp2
        n = fp0-fp2
        s = p1-p2
        r = p0-p2
        denom = r*s*(p0-p1)
        a = (s*n-r*o)/denom
        b = ((r**2)*o-(s**2)*n)/denom
        c = fp2
        count += 1

        #Compute roots
        x1 = (-2*c)/(b+(b**2-4*a*c)**.5)
        x2 = (-2*c)/(b-(b**2-4*a*c)**.5)

        if b>0:
            p3 = p2+x1
        else:
            p3 = p2+x2

        fp3=evalFunction(f,p3)
        print ('{:2}: estimate to a root is f({:18.14f}) = {:18.14f}'.format(count,p3,fp3))
        p2 = p3        

main()
```

Note, I don't see `p0` and `p1` changing inside the loop (so `fp0` and `fp1` also don't change in the loop).  My impression from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muller%27s_method) is that you should be doing something like `p0, p1, p2 = p1, p2, p3` at the point where you say `p2 = p3`.  Also, to reduce function evaluations, you can delete the `fp0`, `fp1` and `fp2` evaluations in the loop, if instead of `p0, p1, p2 = p1, p2, p3` you say `p0, p1, p2, fp0, fp1, fp2 = p1, p2, p3, fp1, fp2, fp3`.

With `p0, p1, p2 = p1, p2, p3` in place of  `p2 = p3`, a much closer result (for a different root) is found in half as many iterations:

```
tini ~/sp/math > ./mullermethod.py '(x-5)*(x-4)*(x+7)' 1 3 -10 0.000001
The initial estimates to a root are:
f( 1.0 ) =  96.0
f( 3.0 ) =  20.0
f( -10.0 ) =  -630.0
 0: estimate to a root is f(  1.00000000000000) =  96.00000000000000
 1: estimate to a root is f( -4.10201287896889) = 213.71097514696675
 2: estimate to a root is f( -6.34710329529507) =  76.65637351948691
 3: estimate to a root is f( -6.95941163108092) =   5.31984100233008
 4: estimate to a root is f( -7.00059085626200) =  -0.07800105634618
 5: estimate to a root is f( -6.99999988135762) =   0.00001566079365
 6: estimate to a root is f( -6.99999999999998) =   0.00000000000281
```

Comment: Thank you for all your input and improvements! To clear up what aspect of the program isn't working for me, it is the reassignment of the points(p0,p1,p2). if I let p2=p3, p1=p2, and p0=p1 at the end of my loop, my program will converge to a root of the function, but not the correct one needed by the given 'correct' output. I also dont understand how in my original code, how I got the correct output for the first iteration, and the second iteration is almost exact except for 1 single digit at the end

Comment: If you say `p2=p3; p1=p2; p0=p1` then all three of p0, p1, p2 will be set equal to p3.  The statement `p0, p1, p2 = p1, p2, p3` doesn't have that problem.  Re wrong root, your `x1=...`, `x2=...`, `if b>0:` sequence may be to blame.  Ie when you choose one denominator or the other, you may be selecting incorrectly (or at least differently) which of course can steer the computation to a different root.  Also, I'd choose denominator before doing a divide, and not compute both of `x1` and `x2`

Comment: Oops, I did it correct in the actual program, but messed it up when typing it on here. I agree that it probably has something to do with that sequence you are suggesting. I have been fiddling with it, and I either come up with the same output or a different output, but never the correct output.

Comment: Do you think that I might need another if statement after the one I already have to reassign the variables differently depending on which p value is closest to the root of the quadratic? Does that make sense?

Comment: No, reassigning the variables differently doesn't make sense. The wikipedia link I gave says "the sign should be chosen such that the denominator is as large as possible in magnitude".  Eg test abs(b-(b**2-4*a*c)**.5) vs abs(b+(b**2-4*a*c)**.5) or possibly the equivalent in complex arithmetic.  Note, you could add a `print` statement for x1, x2, et al, and a `b=int(input())` statement to manually steer the calculation, to find out more about what's going on.  If you find a sequence of b's that gets desired result, then analyze conditions on denom, b, x1, x2, or whatever to get that sequence.